# How to not step into gems when debugging with Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubymine

When debugging a rails application with Rubymine, I would like to step only through code *in* the application, skipping code in gems.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch on the ***Ignore non-project sources* option** in the main settings:

[image]

[Rubymine help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.3/debugger.html?utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=RM&utm_content=2016.3) has the following explanation of the feature:

> Select this check box to automatically skip the external libraries code and keep the focus on your own code.
>   RubyMine will not stop at any non-project code no matter what stepping command is used. This option also prevents opening external files in the editor tabs while debugging.
>
> This option works for Ruby 2.x only; it is not supported for Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.